# Annoying "Create Desktop Entry" popup in Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

Recenty I installed Android Studio on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.
When I created a new project and used Android Studio, this annoying popup kept showing: (Because my low reputation, I cannot post images, please click the link below)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNMbk.png

I tried to check the checkbox but it still display everytime I click on anywhere in Android Studio.
Help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install Android Studio? Using a snap or using the deb package?

Comment: I use .deb package downloaded from home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many times, I decided to reinstall Android Studio and the error disappeared! I don't know the reason clearly but maybe using Create Desktop Entry in Android Studio and creating a .desktop file manually (after installing Android Studio, I wanted to add Android Studio icon to launcher) caused conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for creating a desktop entry: desktop-file-install THE_DESKTOP_FILENAME_HERE.desktop

It might be the solution (if error it's because it localized the fileB, if ok it will copy to the correct localization /usr/share/applications) Restart then

Comment: I run desktop-file-install AndroidStudio.desktop and error showed: "Error on file "AndroidStudio.desktop": No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0):

goto settings in android studio

keymap-> main menu-> tools-> create desk entry

right-click on "create desktop entry"

you will get an option to turn off it.